# Let $F$ be a field with $|F|=q$ and $[K:F]=2$. Let $α∈F$ of order $q-1$. Then there exist an element $β \in K$ of order $q^2-1$ such that $β^{q+1}=α$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Let $F$ be a field with $|F|=q$ and $[K:F]=2$. Let $α∈F$ of order $q-1$. Then there exist an element $β \in K$ of order $q^2-1$ such that $β^{q+1}=α$

Am stuck with finding such a $\beta$ of order $q^2-1$. However since $\gcd(q+1,q^2-1)=q+1$ and $α^{(q^2-1)/(q+1)}=α^{q-1}=1$, I can assure that $x^{q+1}=α$ has solution in $K$. But how to find such an element of order $q^2-1$?

Please help me to proceed! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn’t the solution you found automatically have the right order?

Comment: @Lubin It is not automatic. Consider the case $q=5$. As $8\mid 24=q^2-1$, the group of eighth roots of unity, call it $\mu_8$, is contained in $K$. Raising to sixth power is a $2$-to-$1$ mapping on $\mu_8$, implying that every element of order four is the sixth power of an element of order eight. So in this case with $\alpha$ of order four we have a $\beta$ of order eight such that $\alpha=\beta^6$. True, we can also find a $\beta$ of the prescribed order, but there is this subtlety. I have faced this exact problem at some point. I need to recall how it was resolved :-)

Comment: I think Marc van Leeuwen addressed this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/529698/11619). As I also tried to describe in that thread, that it follows from the fact that whenever $d\mid n$, the projection $\Bbb{Z}_n^*\to\Bbb{Z}_d^*$ is surjective.

Comment: Not voting to close this as a duplicate yet. I have no less than three applicable dupehammers, so my vote would take immediate effect. When I have an answer in the target thread I find it courteous to show some restraint. Particularly as my answer left out a key step. Also, it is likely that we have other threads studying surjectivity of $\Bbb{Z}_n^*\to\Bbb{Z}_d^*$, and those should be included in my opinion.

Comment: Ah, @JyrkiLahtonen , I was thinking too shallowly. Thanks.